# Class/Structure to implement a recursive Interface

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

I need an interface which includes functions which take that same interface type as a parameter. Is that possible?

Basically doing this:

```
Public Interface ICopiable
    Sub CopyFrom(ByVal MyObject As ICopiable)
End Interface

Public Structure User
    Implements ICopiable

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Surname As String

    '# Copy all Member values from another Structure of same Type
    Public Sub CopyFrom(MyUser As User) Implements ICopiable.CopyFrom
        Me.Name = MyUser.Name
        Me.Surname = MyUser.Surname
    End Sub

End Structure
```

At the moment, I get the following error on `Implements ICopiable.CopyFrom`:

> 'CopyFrom' cannot implement 'CopyFrom' because there is no matching Sub on interface 'ICopiable'

I feel this has something to do with a circular reference, where the `Sub`'s argument will only be recognised as an `ICopiable` interface once `User` will be recognised as an `ICopiable` interface, which does not happen until the `Sub` argument is accepted.

Is there any workaround, other than replacing the `Interface` by an `object`? Casting maybe?

```
Public Interface ICopiable
    Sub CopyFrom(ByVal MyObject As Object)
End Interface
```

---

### EDIT

I think there is a flaw in my thinking process: `CopyFrom()` is only able to copy from an object of the **same** type.

That is, `User.CopyFrom(User)` only, whilst the way I defined the `Interface` says `User.CopyFrom(AnyICopiable)`, i.e., the `Interface` says it is aceceptable to have `User.CopyFrom(AnotherObjectThatIsAlsoCopiable)`. This is wrong.

Comment: Is there a problem with implementing the `CopyFrom` method the way it is defined in the interface? `Public Sub CopyFrom(MyObject As ICopiable) Implements ICopiable.CopyFrom`

Comment: Havin `Public Sub CopyFrom(MyUser As ICopiable) Implements ICopiable.CopyFrom` also returns the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this is what you need:

```
Public Interface ICopyable(Of T As ICopyable(Of T))

    Sub CopyFrom(source As T)    

End Interface

Public Structure User
    Implements ICopyable(Of User)

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Surname As String

    Public Sub CopyFrom(source As User) Implements ICopyable(Of User).CopyFrom
        Me.Name = source.Name
        Me.Surname = source.Surname
    End Sub

End Structure
```

That is pretty much the way interfaces like `IComparable(Of T)` are implemented, e.g. the `String` class and `Integer` structure implement `IComparable(Of String)` and `IComparable(Of Integer)` respectively.  Having said that, I'm not sure that such interfaces have a generic type constraint so, in theory, a type could be implemented as being comparable to other types.  In this case, the constraint, i.e. the `As ICopyable(Of T)` part, ensures that a type that implements this interface can only be copied from another instance of the same type.

EDIT:

If you already have a method like this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(copyable As ICopyable)
    '...
End Sub
```

that you want to call like this:

```
Dim user2 As User

user2.CopyFrom(user1)
DoSomething(user2)
```

then, to use my solution, you simply change the method to look like this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(Of T As ICopyable(Of T))(copyable As T)
    '...
End Sub
```

and the call will remain exactly the same.  You can still call the method and pass any object that implements the `ICopyable(Of T)` interface.  As with most generic method calls, `T` will be inferred by the usage.

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Comment: Yeah I also have the feeling the solution will be through Generics.. For example `Sub CopyFrom(Of T)(ByVal MyObject As Object)` in both interface and Structure which implements it. Your solution does not work for me because I have functions which take an `ICopiable` as an argument, and I want it to work with any structure that implements the interface (that is the opoint of the interface no? to avoid having to define the exact `Type`)

Comment: I upvoted you because yet it is a nice piece of case study :)

Comment: See my edit that addresses your concern.  If you can't change the method signatures then you're pretty much screwed though.

Comment: Okay thanks, I think I need to sleep over it. It is quite a Generic-brain-recursive-hache! :') In any cases, I never saw the use of [object] before, so one more thing to study later!

Comment: The use of brackets allows you to use a VB keyword as an identifier, just like in Microsoft flavours of SQL and some others.  I changed my code to use `source` instead of `[object]` because it seemed more descriptive.  For interest's sake, the C# equivalent of `[object]` would be `@object`.

Comment: I just edited my post and then read again yours. That is a perfect fit! Not as pretty as I hopped, but it is the answer!

Comment: However this is adding a lot of complexity to numerous functions I have and which already were Generic, so now I have `Function DoSomething(Of A as B, T as ICopiable(Of T))(Args)`. I think I will just turn back to `CopyFrom(Object)` and `Throw` an `Exception` if the `Type` is not correct. Thanks anyways, very useful and I will certainly reuse this in the future!

Answer (score 0):

A solution without Generics would be doing this, but I would like to avoid if possible:

```
Public Interface ICopiable
    Sub CopyFrom(ByVal MyObject As Object)
End Interface

Public Structure User
    Implements ICopiable

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Surname As String

    '# Copy all Member values from another Structure of same Type
    Public Sub CopyFrom(Of T as ICopiable)(MyUser As Object) Implements ICopiable.CopyFrom
        If Not TypeOf MyUser Is User Then Throw New ArgumentException("Object Type must be User", "MyUser")
        Me.Name = MyUser.Name
        Me.Surname = MyUser.Surname
    End Sub

End Structure
```